# how to set next token to its corresponding jtextfeild

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am reading a CSV file token by token so that each  token belong to a jtextfeild how to do because it shows last token in jtextfeild

```
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
//display csv values
 String setText= st.nextToken();// here what should I do that each JTextFeild get next token;
 ModTxt.setText(); 
 MinSpeedTxt.setText();
 MaxSpeedTxt.setText();
```

Comment: I have this code in JFrame so I directly  want to asssign these tokens to my each JTextFeild

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `nextToken()` to get the next field in your CSV string and set it in your textfield.

```
 ModTxt.setText(st.nextToken()); 
 MinSpeedTxt.setText(st.nextToken());
 MaxSpeedTxt.setText(st.nextToken());
```

Comment: I am getting NoSuchElementException if I do like this

Comment: @user542719 you should first check if there are more tokens by calling `st.hasMoreTokens()` and then call `st.nextToken()`

Comment: in my CSV file some token has empty strings while reading these token I don't want to ignore these empty string  but also want  to read these empty strings how can I do.

Comment: @user542719 StringTokenizer cannot handle empty tokens. Instead of StringTokenizer, use `String.split(",")` which will return an array of tokens.